# Export-CSV with the path as a variable

Tags: variables, powershell, export-to-csv

I have a script that basically writes down each file and folder on a remote share and dumps it to a csv. Everything works wonderfully (there is still a lot of work to be done on the script itself tho) except for the last part.

```cs
Import-Csv -Path ($savelocation + '\' + $filename) -Delimiter ',' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($audioarray -contains $_.Extension) {
        $_.MediaType = 'Audio'
        $_
    } elseif ($videoarray -contains $_.Extension) {
        $_.MediaType = 'Video'
        $_
    } elseif ($otherarray -contains $_.Extension) {
        $_.MediaType = 'Other'
        $_
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path ($savelocation + '\' + $filename) -Force -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

If I change the path to a static location something like `\\servername\share\testfolder` it works fine. But if I use the above or even if I join the `($savelocation + '\' + $filename)` into something like `$filename` it still just writes an empty file.

Comment: Do `Write-Host ($savelocation + '\' + $filename)` ... What do you get?

Comment: C:\Temp\NFDW1004-C$Progra~1-2012-5-25.csv - I also use the exact same naming convention twice before to write the file originally and then to add an extra csv header MediaType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but it won't work for any path. Reason is simple - you read/write to the same file. It *would* work, if you would read into variable, and work on data in memory.

IMO having a path (elements) stored in variable have nothing to do with it. BTW: you can join paths with Join-Path cmdlet... :)

Comment: And of course its the easiest answer that was staring me in the face. It was indeed the fact the file is the same file. I will just dump to a temp file and delete and rename it.

Comment: If you want to write data back to the same file without writing to a temp file and subsequently replacing the original you can do so by putting the reading statement in parentheses (`(Import-Csv $csv) | ForEach-Object {...} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType`). Beware that this will read the entire file into memory, so it's not suitable for processing large files.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you put the path in a veriable instead

```
$path = $savelocation + '\' + $filename
Export-Csv -Path $path -Force -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: No, it won't. The problem is that when you read and write the same file in a pipeline, the writing statement will already start writing to the file before the reading statement has had a chance to read it, thus effectively truncating the file. Putting the filename in a variable doesn't change anything about that.